# How to merge consecutive record pairs over a table?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I have a table where I need to merge consecutive record pairs (when ordered by `id`, `data` and `from`). Note that for pairs being merged, the first row's `prevfrom` is `NULL` and the second row's `nextto` is `NULL`.

```
id  data from        to          prevfrom    nextto
1   a    2015-01-01  2015-01-05  NULL        2015-01-10
1   a    2015-01-10  2015-01-14  2015-01-05  NULL
1   a    2015-01-15  2015-01-20  NULL        2015-01-22
1   a    2015-01-30  2015-02-04  2015-01-25  NULL
2   c    2015-01-01  2015-01-05  NULL        2015-01-10
2   c    2015-01-05  2015-01-10  2015-01-01  NULL
```

So in this case, I would want to merge rows 1&2, 3&4, and 5&6, and discard helper columns `prevfrom` and `nextto`. As a result of the merge, each row would have `from` value of the first record in the pair, and `to` value of the second record in the pair. Like so:

```
id  data from        to          
1   a    2015-01-01  2015-01-14  
1   a    2015-01-15  2015-02-04  
2   c    2015-01-01  2015-01-10
```

I can do this by doing a `SELECT` and a `JOIN` inside a `WHILE` loop until I run out of record pairs (pseudo code):

```
WHILE table exists DO:  
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO #temp
    SELECT TOP 2 * FROM table ORDER BY [id],[data],[from]  --get a pair
  INSERT INTO result            --join #temp with itself to merge rows
    SELECT t1.[id],t1.[data],t1.[from], t2.[to]
    FROM #temp AS t1
    JOIN #temp AS t2
      ON t1.[from]<t2.[from]    --later record joined on earlier record
  DELETE FROM table             --update original table
    IF record exists IN #temp
  TRUNCATE TABLE #temp          --empty temp table for next insertion
END
```

However I feel that doing an `ORDER BY` in every iteration is inefficient. Is there a simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, use common table expressions to isolate and number rows in 2 groups with one helper column `NULL` in each, and then join the two groups on row numbers.

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT [id], [data], [from] , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [id], [data], [from]) AS [row]
        FROM #temp3
        WHERE [prevfrom] IS NULL),
    cte2 AS (
    SELECT [to], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [id], [data], [from]) AS [row]
        FROM #temp3
        WHERE [nextto] IS NULL)
SELECT t1.id, t1.data, t1.from, t2.to
    FROM cte1 AS t1
    JOIN cte2 AS t2
    ON t1.[row]=t2.[row];
```